# Is that true that neutron activity on Earth in 2013 is unusual?

Tags: popular-science, neutrons, solar-wind

I have just read curious statement on this website: http://www.trinitas.ru/rus/doc/0016/001d/00162241.htm (unfortunately this is in Russian, but I will try to translate)

"В заключение можно отметить, что всплески потоков частиц, не связанных с солнечными вспышками, по данным нейтронных мониторов впервые стали наблюдаться в 2013г."

"In conclusion we can say that splashes (on charts) that are not connected to the solar flashes, according to the neutron monitors are observed for the first time ever started in 2013."

The website also links to http://www.bartol.udel.edu/gp/neutronm/ as to the source of data used for analysis.

Can anyone please confirm or reject this statement?

Te authors suggest that there is some sort of increased underground neutron activity, that is detected by the monitors. And that previously nothing (on that scale) like that was ever detected, in other words it was thought that most neutrons come from solar flashes and now many of neutrons come from somewhere else.

Comment: Just skimming through the topics on that website, I'd take anything coming from there with a pinch of salt. Has it been published in a peer-reviewed journal?

Comment: raskolnikov, I have no idea, I see that site for the first time, I think I followed the link from the expert.ru website to get there. I share your suspicions about their reputations. I was looking for pseudo-science tag while asking this question, but only got `pop-science`.

Comment: Can solar neutrons make it to the Earth?  I don't see how they could get accelerated since they're neutral and with their short half-life I don't see how they could make it to the Earth without decaying into a proton.

Comment: So neutron spalation from cosmic rays is real thing and a significant source of background even in deep-underground, low-background detector system. The University of Deleware link looks to be legit. However, they seem impressed with a ground level enhancement (GLE) from 2005 rather than more recently than that.

Comment: More. If something interesting has happened recently the UD people didn't take the time to post it to their webpage, but then it would have to be pretty big indeed to compare to the two they do link from [2005](http://www.bartol.udel.edu/gp/neutronm/gle2005.html) and [2006](http://www.bartol.udel.edu/gp/neutronm/solmin_gle.jpg). I read the [currently reported values](http://neutronm.bartol.udel.edu/~pyle/Spectral.png) (from a limited number of stations) to be only 5-10% enhanced.

Comment: @BrandonEnright - Neutrons can be produced by nuclear reactions in the solar atmosphere (e.g., spallation).  If their kinetic energy is high enough upon ejection from the nucleus, their lifetimes can be dilated due to relativistic effects.  Their typical (lab frame) lifetimes are on the order of ~800 seconds, but at relativistic energies this can be arbitrarily increased.  So yes, it is possible to measure neutrons produced at the sun, as stated in this [PDF](http://pamela.roma2.infn.it/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_view&gid=359).